# How to generate tabular output in reStructuredText without using RST table format?

Tags: python-sphinx, tablelayout, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm trying to migrate our API docs and their proprietary documentation generator schema to reStructuredText. The piece that gives the hardest time is, we have a tabular representation of API details, coded directly in HTML, a la:

```
--------+------------+--------+--------------------------------+
Param   |  Required  |  Type  |  Description
----------------------------------------------------------------
id      |     Yes    | int    | This is the ID of the record...
content |     No     | string | Optional string contents...
```

(i.e. this is currently coded as `<tr><td class='param'>id</td><td class='required'>Yes</td>...`)

I want to do this in RST but do it *semantically*, rather than just using an RST table format. But I can't find any good examples of [custom directives](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-directives.html) to handle this the way I want, which would be something like

```
:.. parameter-table:: My Parameter Table
    .. item::
       :param: "id"
       :required: true
       :type: "int"
       :desc: "This is the ID of the record..."
```

How can I accomplish this in reStructuredText?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom directive.  Have you tried using a standard restructuredText [List Table](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table)?

It looks something like this (from the linked page):

```
.. list-table:: Frozen Delights!
   :widths: 15 10 30
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Treat
     - Quantity
     - Description
   * - Albatross
     - 2.99
     - On a stick!
   * - Crunchy Frog
     - 1.49
     - If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
       crunchy, now would it?
   * - Gannet Ripple
     - 1.99
     - On a stick!
```

The table headers are in the first outer list item (in this example, at least).  Even if this isn't exactly what you want I think this will get you at least 90% of the way there.

Comment: I like this one. I agree it's only 90% -- I would prefer if the fields were more explicitly "fields" instead of just positional -- but it is simple and clean enough that it's probably better than the complexity of a custom directive. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way this can be auto-generated using any plugins? Like I have multiple tables to be created with different rows and columns. I am looking a way to generate these faster.